# RegisterCreatureEvent specifying multiple creatures in Lua script

Tags: lua, azerothcore, eluna-lua-engine

In "RegisterCreatureEvent( entry, event, function )", it defines entry as "The ID of one or more Creatures". How do I go about specifying multiple creatures?

Edit: It was pointed out to me that creatures is plural because there can be more than one copy of a creature spawned in the world. You cannot specify multiple entries in RegisterCreatureEvent.

Answer (score 0):

The library implements the id only as a number, so you cannot provide multiple ids in a table.

https://github.com/ElunaLuaEngine/Eluna/blob/8f5c4699b2531c408b615f55270541a7267c742b/GlobalMethods.h

You should try to use Creature familiy ids here.

http://elunaluaengine.github.io/Creature/GetCreatureFamily.html

`CREATURE_FAMILY_VOIDWALKER` can perhaps be used to register events for all voidwalkers.

But that's just a guess from reading the docs and some sourcode. I have no way to test this.